# Idiomatic way to reply to Google Groups mailing list with Gnus

Tags: email, emacs, gmail, gnus

I'm subscribed to a mailing list on Google Groups. Before, i used to reply to people outside mailing list by pressing `r` (`gnus-summary-reply`). For list this is no good — the reply is sent directly to the author, not the mailing list. I've found pressing `f` (`gnus-summary-followup`) is better, as it includes the mailing list too. So if "Person A" started a thread, "Person B" replied to them, my reply's e-mail headers are:

```
To: "Person B" <b@foomail.org>
Cc: "Person A" <a@gmail.com>,  "foolist@googlegroups.com" <foolist@googlegroups.com>
Subject: Re: [FOOLIST] Bar topic
From: me@mail.net (me@mail.net)
```

But I'm not sure if i should send copy to both persons A and B. Will they receive duplicate letters if one is on Gmail and another on some random mail server? If i send directly to mailing list instead, will my reply appear in correct position in a tree?

What is the best and correct way to reply to mailing lists via Gnus?